# Need to clear client side validation error message of TextBoxFor @type="file" (File Upload) when user uploads valid file

Tags: model-view-controller, razor, file-upload

The validation that I've got correctly shows the error message if the user clicks the Submit button at the very bottom of the page without having uploaded a valid file. The issue is that when the user successfully uploads a valid file, I need that error message to clear immediately as it does for a TextBoxFor.

I have:

```
    [RegularExpression(@"([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.pdf|.jpg|.png|.rtf|.doc|.docx)$", ErrorMessage = "Files must be pdf, jpg, png, rtf, doc, or docx.")]
    [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
    [Display(Name = "Survey (Required)")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select file.")]
    public HttpPostedFileBase Survey { get; set; }
```

and

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => Model.Survey, new { @class = "control-label" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Survey, new { @class = "form-control", @type = "file", Name = "Survey" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.Survey, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this to clear the validation error:

```
//04/10/20 kk Had to do the below to clear the val immediately on selection
$("#Survey").change(function () {
    $("#Survey").blur(); 
});
```